# Sum of component projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression

Show that if $X$ $=$ [$X_1$ $X_2]$ and $X_1'X_2 = 0$, then $P = P_1 + P_2$, where $P$ is defined as $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$, the projection matrix.

Don't quite know where to start. I tried evaluating it by brute force, but there must be an easier way, surely? Don't quite want to deal with taking the inverse of a partitioned matrix. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: They are the projections of $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively. So, $P_1$ would be $X_1(X_1'X_1)^{-1}X_1'$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply put $X=[X_1 X_2]$ into $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.
$P=[X_1 \ \ X_2]\begin{bmatrix}
(X_1^TX_1)^{-1} & 0\\ 
 0 &  (X_2^TX_2)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
X_1^T\\ 
X_2^T
\end{bmatrix}=X_1(X_1^TX_1)^{-1}X_1^T + X_2(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^T = P_1 + P_2$.
Because $X_1^TX_2=0$, so the inverse is for an block-diagonal matrix, which is easy to compute analytically.